# Extraction of data from a given column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-extraction

I would like to know if there is a way of extracting information from a given column concerning a company.

That column contains several companies

```
  |ID|Date|Sales|Company|Gross to Net Discount|
   1 --------------A----------------------------

   2 --------------A----------------------------

   . --------------B----------------------------

   .---------------C----------------------------

   .---------------D----------------------------

   50000 ----------A----------------------------
```

I only want a table with all that information but only for company A.

How to carry out such data analysis?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for the naive question though! :)

Comment: No worries. It takes some time to get a hang of searching methods to find an answer on SO.